# Grid cards on bootstrap for React is displaying the same element four times, instead of different elements 4 times

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to apply tome styling to one lab, using the cards from bootstrap.

I want it to display 4 elements horizontal per row, it is working BUT, is showing the same element 4 times and the idea is to show 4 different elements per row. Can somebody please help me?

[image: Screenshot showing bootstrap cards]

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import Navbars from "./Navbars";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';


const Beers = ({ beers }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbars />
      {beers.map((beer) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <Row xs={1} md={4} className="g-4">
              {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) => (
                <Col>
                  <Card>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={beer.image_url} alt="" />
                    <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Title>{beer.name}</Card.Title>
                      <Card.Text>
                        {beer.tagline}
                      </Card.Text>
                    </Card.Body>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              ))}
            </Row>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Beers;
```

I tried switching the `{beers.map((beer)` to `.map((_, idx)` but it didn't work, I also try leaving only one return by putting `{beers.map((beer)` before the first `return` but it also didn't work.